# TSQL Combining Multiple Rows Into One Row

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a query to combine the following information:

```
FileID  ErrorCode  ErrorDesc             ErrorCount
  1         4      Bad File Name             3
  2         6      Bad File Code            56
  3         4      Bad File Name             2
  3        12      Line Length Invalid       3
  3        17      Missing Req Fields      150
```

I want to combine all rows based on the `FileID` so that all information for a given `FileID` would appear on the same line as the following:

```
1  4  Bad File Name     3
2  6  Bad File Code    56
3  4  Bad File Name     2     12  Line Length Invalid  3     17 Missing Req Fields  150
```

The problem I am running it to there will be an unknown amount of errors per given file. It could have 1-50 errors and I would like to combine all of that information under one row. I am not sure if this is possible or if there is another way to look at this issue. My end goal is to end up creating a report off of this data. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a max number of rows for any given FileID? Is the list of ErrorCodes known and finite? If there are two error 12s do you need to report both of them separately? In any case, I'd suggest this collapsing will be better handled at the presentation tier.

Comment: There would be a max number of rows based on the total number of errors. In this case with 50 errors the would be a max of 50 entries per FileID. All error codes will be unique per given file. So One FileID will only have each error code listed once.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! (and no messy `&nbsp;` and `<br/>` needed, either!!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little more involved than Mikael's - the main difference is that columns are maintained here (however the columns for each error code other than the first "line up").

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t
(
    FileID INT,
    ErrorCode INT,
    ErrorDesc VARCHAR(255),
    ErrorCount INT
);

INSERT dbo.t VALUES
(1,4,'Bad File Name',3),
(2,6,'Bad File Code',56),
(3,4,'Bad File Name',2),
(3,12,'Line Length Invalid',3),
(3,17,'Missing Req Fields',150);
```

Code:

```
DECLARE 
    @sql0 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
    @sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
    @sql2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
    @minC INT;

SELECT @minC = MIN(ErrorCode) FROM dbo.t;

SELECT @sql1 += REPLACE(',x$.ErrorCode AS Code$,
    x$.ErrorDesc AS Desc$,x$.ErrorCount AS Count$', 
    '$', CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ErrorCode))
    FROM dbo.t WHERE ErrorCode > @minC GROUP BY ErrorCode ORDER BY ErrorCode;

SELECT @sql2 += REPLACE(' 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN x AS x$ ON z.FileID = x$.FileID 
    AND x$.ErrorCode = $
    AND x$.ErrorCode > z.ErrorCode', '$', CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ErrorCode))
    FROM dbo.t WHERE ErrorCode > @minC GROUP BY ErrorCode ORDER BY ErrorCode;

SET @sql0 = ';WITH y AS (
    SELECT FileID, ErrorCode, ErrorDesc, ErrorCount,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FileID ORDER BY ErrorCode)
    FROM dbo.t
),
z AS ( SELECT FileID, ErrorCode, ErrorDesc, ErrorCount FROM y WHERE rn = 1 ),
x AS ( SELECT FileID, ErrorCode, ErrorDesc, ErrorCount FROM y WHERE rn > 1 )
SELECT z.*' + @sql1 + ' FROM z
' + @sql2;

-- PRINT @sql0; -- to see what has been crafted    
EXEC sp_executesql @sql0;
GO
```

Clean-up:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.t;
GO
```

Comment: +1 of course. I'm looking at it and... well It could be because I'm cooking dinner for my kids but I don't get it. Have to sit down for a while to understand what you did here :)

Comment: Just an anchor and a bunch of left joins. I'm not 100% happy with it, because there are going to be null columns for any ErrorCode that is the lowest for any FileID but doesn't appear in any other rank. I still think the presentation tier is where this should be handled...

Comment: That's impressive. It's gets exactly what I was trying to figure out, it is rather complicated, but very interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
declare @T table (FileID int, ErrorCode int, ErrorDesc varchar(max), ErrorCount int)

insert into @T values
(1,             4,                    'Bad File Name',          3),
(2,             6,                    'Bad File Code',          56),
(3,             4,                    'Bad File Name',          2),
(3,             12,                   'Line Length Invalid',    3),
(3,             17,                   'Missing Req Fields',     150)

select FileID,
       (select cast(ErrorCode as varchar(10))+' '+ErrorDesc+' '+cast(ErrorCount as varchar(10))+' '
        from @T as T2
        where T1.FileID = T2.FileID
        for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)') 
from @T as T1
group by FileID
```

Comment: I would like to do it without combining them into one column. Thoughts?

Comment: @buzzzzjay - Go with the answer given by by Aaron. Dynamics is the only way to have "unknown/variable" number of columns that I know of.

Comment: @buzzzzjay you are really making things harder for yourself with the solution you are requesting.